# what is a number in joint_states/positions[2] in rqt?

Tags: ros, joint-states, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi .
For show plot of my robot I want use joint_states/positions[2]. what is 2 in command?
The two refers to the third joint in URDF ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252414/what-is-a-number-in-joint_states/positions%5B2%5D--in-rqt-?/) by [zakizadeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27970/zakizadeh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 217 on 2017-01-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The two refers to the third joint, whose name you get at joints_states/name[2].

BTW: please invest some seconds in roughly correct spelling.

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2017-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zakizadeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27970/zakizadeh/) on 2017-01-19**:
The two refers to the third joint in URDF ??

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-01-20**:
Yes. This is common in computer science and is referred to as 0-based indexing: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering